# C# How to determine the time required to perform the push/pop or queue/dequeue operations on stacks and queues

Tags: c#, stack

Part of my task is to get the time required to push 10,000,000 values onto each stack and then get the time required to pop 10,000,000 values from each stack. I have code written out so far for my stacks and it looks like this I used 1,000,000 because 10,000,000 took too long.

```
    Console.WriteLine ("The StackO stack : " + '\t' + " "); 

        for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++) 
        {
            DateTime stackOstartTime = DateTime.Now;
            Stack StackO = new Stack ();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000*n; i++)
            {
                StackO.Push (i);

            }

DateTime stackOendTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan stackOtimeDifference = stackOendTime - stackOstartTime;
Console.WriteLine ("It took the number: " + n + "  " + stackOtimeDifference + " to push.");
```

The part that I am stuck on his how to pop these values out of my stack and then get the time required to do that as well. I have tried making a similar implementation by replacing StackO.Push(i) with StackO.Pop() and I do not get anything. I have been trying many different things and I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated, and if my stack push implementation is incorrect any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my output:
    The StackO stack :
    It took the number: 1  00:00:00.1358860 to push.
    It took the number: 2  00:00:00.2481400 to push.
    It took the number: 3  00:00:00.4524940 to push.
    It took the number: 4  00:00:00.5205040 to push.
    It took the number: 5  00:00:00.7325030 to push.
    It took the number: 6  00:00:00.6901880 to push.
    It took the number: 7  00:00:00.9433310 to push.
    It took the number: 8  00:00:01.1270300 to push.
    It took the number: 9  00:00:01.0711620 to push.
    It took the number: 10  00:00:01.3230030 to push.

Comment: Try `int i = StackO.Pop();` and see what you get.

Comment: `DateTime` should be avoided when doing performance metrics,  use `StopWatch` instead.

Comment: Also, use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`.

Comment: @jstreet Where would I put int i = StackO.Pop();? i is already declared in the for loop so I'm getting this error "a local variable named i cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning..etc "

Comment: You would put it, for instance, in a loop just like the one you did for the `Push()` part of your code. Also, you don't need to use `i` as a variable, you can use any other variable name you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution of the clock that drives `System.DateTime` is not particularly good.  As a couple of people have suggested you need to use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to get better timing information:

```
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
int numItems = 50000000;
var stack = new Stack<int>();

sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i)
    stack.Push(i);
sw.Stop();
var totalTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

Console.WriteLine("Push time: {0:#,#0.00}ms", 1000 * totalTime);
Console.WriteLine("Time per item: {0:#,#0.00}ns", (1000000000.0 * totalTime) / numItems);
```

Running this on my dev machine (it's a virtual, so stats are a bit hazy :P) gives the following output:

```
Push time: 1,278.07ms
Time per item: 25.56ns
```

That's 50 million items pushed in just over a second, with an average of around 25 nanoseconds per item inserted.  Over several runs I get a fairly wide variance, but that's a fairly typical number.

For the pop measures, directly after the above:

```
int val;
sw.Restart();
while (stack.Any())
    val = stack.Pop();
sw.Stop();
totalTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
Console.WriteLine("Pop time: {0:#,#0.00}ms", 1000 * totalTime);
Console.WriteLine("Time per item: {0:#,#0.00}ns", (1e+9 * totalTime) / numItems);
```

Output times for this were much longer:

```
Pop time: 5,067.17ms
Time per item: 101.34ns
```

About 4 times as long to pop as to push, which is interesting.  Subsequent tests had the ratio varying between 3 and 5 times.

Now here's what you get from measuring 1000 items:

```
Push time: 0.06ms
Time per item: 64.60ns

Pop time: 0.40ms
Time per item: 402.70ns
```

Because of the scale difference the error resolution is pretty poor, but here you get actual results.  I put some `DateTime.Now` recording in and ran the thing again, with results that were so far off the real times that they were utterly worthless - 2ms instead of 0.06ms, then 1ms instead of 0.4ms.

So if you are measuring very small time spans use a `Stopwatch`.  If the times are long (at least a second) and you just want a rough figure then use `DateTime`.  But since `Stopwatch` is so simple to use it's generally going to be the best option.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. And also the others that told me that stop watch is much better, I can see that now. This plus your explanations were very helpful. I am going to try this with the rest of my queue classes and their implementations. I will get back to you if I have anymore questions.

Comment: I did have a question. When I use Stack.Any() I get a System.Collections.Generic.Stack does not contain a definition for 'Any'. error and I also get the same error with my queue class. Any reason why that might be? Am I missing a system? These are what I am currently using using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

Comment: @Somone You are probably missing `using System.Linq;`  The `Any()` extension lives there.

Comment: With .NET 8, using `while (stack.Count != 0)` instead of `.Any()` is much faster. Decreasing POP time from an average of 660ms down to 147ms

Comment: @Damian Agreed. The point of this was mainly to show that timing using the system clock (via `DateTimne.Now`) instead of `Stopwatch` will give absolutely garbage results. Arguably using `stack.Count` is faster on all versions of dotnet and FW.